# Swift set orientation to specific screen in code

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I want to programaticlly set a ViewController orientation and after dismissing the ViewController i want the orientation to return to previous mode

This is what i currently use:

```
if(GamePrefrences.orientation == "landscape")
    {
        value = UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft.rawValue
    }
    else
    {
        value = UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue
    }
```

Comment: Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/a/30938224/1422333

Answer (score 3):

> You can override the preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation for
>   a view controller that is intended to be presented full screen in a
>   specific orientation.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/